# Magento 2: New Order Status is not displaying in Listing

Tags: magento2, orders, custom

In Admin on Order Status :- Complete state I added new order status "Collect", "Deliver".

I have changed order status with script so it changes in `sales_order` table state & status.

With script it's changing state & status in Database.

I already done indexing.

When I go to **Admin -> Sales -> Order** list it always show Complete in listing. When i go to that order detail page then it displays my new Collect/Deliver status.

**Why it's not displaying in Listing?**

Comment: have you checked dataScource of listing ?

Comment: HI @RonakChauhan I have checked `magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options.php` & it's displaying my new status in Array. But not in Listing

Comment: override that class and re-assign your status